# AutoSys - Update common attribute in multiple JILs

Tags: autosys

Have scoured the net but was not able to find anything fruitful.

Assume that i have 5 boxes within 5 jobs within each.
I would want to update a common attribute within each one of those jobs.

Is there a way to perform the update to that attribute using a single update_job statement rather than having 25 lines of update_job commands for each job?

Zz

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can just use for example:

```
update_job: job_name
condition: s(job_name1)
update_job: job_name_a
condition: s(job_name2)
update_job: job_name_b
condition: s(job_name3)
```

Dave

Comment: I was looking for something more like this - update_job: jobname, jobname2, jobname3 no_retry=0. Is something like this possible rather than having individual entries for each job?

Comment: no you need to have each job seperate with its new value. Dave